# Logical mask in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use a logical array mask to square all the values of  this array a = [1:1:2000}. The logical array mask is defined as b = a <500. 
How would I square those values using the mask?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a = 1:2000; %# 1 by 2000 double
b = a<500;  %# 1 by 2000 logical    
a_squared     = a(b).^2; %# 1 by 499 double
%# logical index--^ ^-- 'dot' means element-wise operation
```

Comment: Thank you ! Hard to be a newbee ^^

Answer (score 2):

If you need the result to be the same size as `a` (keeping `a >= 500` values as is), then:

```
a_sq = (a .^ 2) .* (a < 500) + a .* (a >= 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one, more tricky. Here we apply logical mask to the power, which gets values 1 or 2.

```
a_sq = a .^ (2 - (a >= 500));
```