# How to extract a part of a matrix with condition in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, extract

I have a sat of matrices and I want to extract only a part of the matrix that satisfy a condition.

For example: values of the `150x180` matrix goes from `0` to `2.80` and I only want those between `1.66` and `1.77`
I want to keep the values within the rang in their original location in the original matrix and set the other to zero.

can anybody help me please.

Thank you

Comment: Use [logical indexing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233370/logical-mask-in-matlab)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use logical indexing. First, find `A` entries that do not satisfy your conditions. Next, using `A(idx)` change them to 0:

```
% example matrix
A = 2.8*rand(150, 180);

% find entries meeting some criterion
idx = A<1.66 | A>1.77;
A(idx) = 0;
```

Or simpler, as Rody Oldenhuis suggested, you can include the logical expression directly in the matrix reference:

```
A(A<1.66 | A>1.77) = 0;
```

This yields a shorter and cleaner code, but not a faster code: MATLAB still explicitly creates the logical index variable, but clears it afterwards.

Comment: @AliOsaca Since you are a new user, I suggest you go through all your questions and check the 'accept' sign at the answer that solved your problem. This is how SO questions and answers function. This will motivate others to help you in the future.

Comment: Or skip the temporary and do `A(A<1.66|A>1.77) = 0`

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I would love that method to skip the temporary variable. However, in reality Matlab still creates a logical index variable... unfortunately.

Comment: @angainor: You're right, I meant skipping the explicit storage of the indices in the variable `idx`, so you can skip the `clear idx`.